# TestFlight desktop app v1.0 not working on OSX Yosemite v10.10?

Tags: ios, macos, testflight, osx-yosemite

I have just updated my OSX to Yosemite, then I ran into an error when submitting a new build to TestFlight with the TestFlight desktop app.

> error: /usr/bin/codesign --force
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign 2c30db522ceda29332f9f85951addff0276e0de1
>   --resource-rules=/tmp/sesLW20J9I/Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist /tmp/sesLW20J9I/Payload/MyApp.app failed with error 1. Output:
>   Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules"
>   (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)! Warning: --resource-rules has been
>   deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
>   /tmp/sesLW20J9I/Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read
>   resources

Anyone has got an idea?

Comment: Note to whoever flagged this as off-topic: FYI, questions specific to software tools primarily used by developers are on-topic at SO. (The [close votes review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6260057) ended with a unanimous vote to leave open.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OK, finally I find a solution to this issue. It seems that the resource rules file is not generated by default in XCode 6.1.

To generate the resource rules file as before, go to project setting, search for

**Code Signing Resource Rules Path**, and set its value as

> $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist

After this change, rebuild your target, TestFlight desktop app will work as before.

Comment: Thanks! I just f**** with the manual process of export a archive in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

The app has not been updated to work on Yosemite (and I doubt it ever will because it was developed before Apple acquired TestFlight iirc and Apple has integrated the uploading process into Xcode.